# angular checkbox list manipulation

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router

I have multiple columns in my list and I want to add checkboxes to my index. I want to be able to check the boxes to get the filtered list and when uncheck them, of course it should give me the correct result. I am not sure the best way to achieve that. some posts were talking about watcher and others were suggestion just array of data to push to. I tried pushing to an array and then set it to $scope.cars but the problem is that it is just too much work to get back my original $scope.car. So I dropped that idea. Now I am waiting for a better solution. Here is my code

script.js

```
// Code goes here

var app = angular.module('myapp', []);

app.controller('DemoCtrl', [ '$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.q = '';
  $scope.cars = [
  {
    year: 2006,
    make: 'BMW',
    model: 'M3'
  },
  {
    year: 2006, 
    make: 'BMW',
    model: 'Z4'
  },
  {
    year: 1992, 
    make: 'Mazda',
    model: 'Miata'
  },
  {
    year: 2008, 
    make: 'BMW special',
    model: '750'
  }
  ];


}]);
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myapp">

  <head>
    <link data-require="bootstrap-css@3.1.1" data-semver="3.1.1" rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.3.0-beta.5" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.5/angular.js"></script>
    <script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="2.1.1" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script data-require="bootstrap@*" data-semver="3.1.1" src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div ng-controller="DemoCtrl">

        <input type="checkbox">BMW
        <span style="margin-left:20px;"></span><input type="checkbox">Mazda</span>


      <input class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="q" placeholder="Search by year, make, model" />
      <br/>
      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="car in cars | filter:filterCars">{{car.year}} {{car.make}} {{car.model}}</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

and her eis plunker
http://plnkr.co/edit/QXPYKBkH6u7N374yjQHV?p=preview

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by setting `ng-model` on checkboxes and using that model in `ng-repeat` filter

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="filters.mfgr" ng-true-value="BMW"  ng-false-value="">

<li ng-repeat="car in cars | filter:{make:filters.mfgr}">
```

To combine the text search and checkboxes make a custom filter that accepts both models as arguments

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/Qua6TgYtZjP6BFkoiwDt?p=preview)**</kbd>

Comment: nice. Only issue that it does not let me select both and works like radio button...not checkbox.